# Paging Enabled ScrollViewのスクロール量を設定する

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

`Storyboard`上にある`ScrollView`の`Paging Enabled`にチェックを入れ、1ページずつ画像をスクロールするようにしたのですが、1ページずつではなく指定した数値分だけ画像をスクロールさせたいです。つまり、1ページ内で複数回ページングさせたいです。このような場合どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の内容に関して、"指定した数値分だけ"の所は「複数ページを一度にスクロールさせたい」のか又は「1ページ内で複数回ページングさせたい」のかを明確にすると回答し易くなると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、内容を編集いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

本家に最適な回答を発見しましたので、記載します。

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageNumberYouWantToGoTo;//ページ数
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

[参考　Change page on UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926830)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
色々と試してみたのですが、スムーズに動いてくれません。
ですが考え方的にはこのようになるのではないかと思うので、ご提示いただいた方法でもう少し頑張ってみたいと思います。